# Reusing an asssembly in many projects

Tags: .net, assemblies

I've a custom .NET assembly that is used in many projects. Currently whenever I build that custom assembly I'm replacing all the projects that refers this assembly with the new binary. Other than GAC is there any better way to avoid this overhead in .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just include the single project in each of your solutions? Then when you rebuild the solution, you'll end up using the latest code.

Alternatively, if you want to build against the binary, have a single location relative to all your solutions which always has the latest version, and just build against that.

Comment: I'll do like that but I thought there may be a better way.

Comment: @Mark: It seems like a pretty simple way to get it working to me. There are more complex solutions like NuGet which you might want to look into, of course...